# Can I use 'monarch-appointed' as a compound adjective (for example, 'a monarch-appointed prime-minister')?

Tags: word-formation

I want to refrain from using an adjectival phrase because I would prefer to avoid any confusion ('Governorate-generals were headed by governors-general appointed by monarchs whose job was to keep an eye on governors under their supervision,' it's not clear whether it was monarchs' or governors-general's job).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Monarch-appointed" is perfectly fine as a compound adjective. However, "prime minister" is *not* a compound adjective and should be written without the hyphen.

Another possibility to avoid the ambiguity you described is:

> Governorate-generals were headed by governors-general appointed by monarchs, and their job was to keep an eye on governors under their supervision.

Comment: Thanks, but your suggestion is not much better. It's still not 100% clear whether 'their' refers to 'monarchs' or 'governors-general'

Comment: @SergeyZoloratev Actually, it should technically refer to "governorate-generals," the subject of the first clause. So your choice probably is the best.